Expected Value of Posterior distribution where the function has cases.
Assume I have a prior over two random variables  $\theta_A \sim U[0,\hat{\theta_A}], \theta_B \sim U[0,\hat{\theta_B}]$. Let's say I observe $x = 1$ if $\theta_B b + \theta_A a > z$  and $=0$ otherwise.
Assume that $ \hat{\theta_A} a > z \: \& \: \hat{\theta_B}b > z$.
I want to compute the expected value of $\theta_A | x = 1$.
I think I can compute my posterior density function of $\theta_A$ as:
$$
f(\theta_A| x = 1)  \propto  \begin{cases}
   \hat{\theta}_B - \frac{z}{b} + \frac{\theta_A a}{b} &  0 < \theta_A < \frac{z}{a} \\ 
  \hat{\theta}_B  &  \frac{z}{a}  <  \theta_A \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
With the normalizing constant of $ k = \hat{\theta_A}\hat{ \theta_B } - \frac{z^2}{ab}$.
But I am struggling to find the expected value of the $\theta_A|x=1$. I tried computing the expected value of both conditions as and adding them together:
$$ \int^{z/a}_0 \frac{\theta_A}{k} ( \hat{\theta}_B - \frac{z}{b} + \frac{\theta_A   a}{b}) d \theta_A  + \frac{\hat{\theta_B}}{k} \times \frac{\hat{\theta_A} + z/a }{2}  $$
and I get an answer that doesn't make sense.
I think either
(a) I have not correctly specified the expected value for the uniform function in the latter part of the integral,
(b) I am not supposed to simply add the expected values together.
But I am struggling to see where I am going wrong.
